# Block Adyen status in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, payment, adyen

In the module of adyen no magento, I wanted to block any notification that is made through a bank slip. The ProcessNotification.php file from the following path: app/code/community/Adyen/Payment/Model is responsible for processing any notification from the Adyen servers and from the following code, I can block all notification, whatever the method of payment.

**Code:**

```
$eventCode = trim($params->getData('eventCode'));
if ($eventCode == Adyen_Payment_Model_Event:: AUTHORISATION) {
    $this->_debugData['processResponse info'] = 'Skip notification REPORT_AVAILABLE';
    $this->_debug($storeId);
    return;
}
```

With the following code, from the event of payment confirmation, I block all notification, but it ends up that includes notifications that are shopping from credit card and I wanted to block only the notifications that are from bank slip.

Comment: Are you trying to block a specific payment method's notification?

Comment: Yes, in case it would be the bank slip method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that I did to solve this question was the following:

```
$eventCode = trim($params->getData('eventCode'));
if ($eventCode == Adyen_Payment_Model_Event::ADYEN_EVENT_AUTHORISATION){
    $payment = $params->getData('paymentMethod');
    if($payment == "boletobancario_santander") {
        $this->_debugData['processResponse info'] = 'Skip notification REPORT_AVAILABLE';
        $this->_debug($storeId);
        return;
    }
}
```